# How to set value to a session state in streamlits?

Tags: python, streamlit

i'm new to streamlit and i tried to create a budgeting apps in Streamlit.
i have the following functions:

```
#the purpose of this function are:
# create a st.number_input
# store its value in sessions
def input_number(labelnya,session_name,value=None,help=None,format='%g'):
    valuenya = st.number_input(labelnya,value=value,help=help,format=format)
    valuenya = 0 if valuenya is None else valuenya
    if session_name not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state[session_name] = valuenya
    print("All Session:\n{}".format(st.session_state))
    return valuenya
```

then, i want session_state store something like this:

```
{
    "asset": {
        "asset1": {
            "cash_on_hand": 1,
            "account_receivable": 2
        },
        "asset2": {}
    },
    "liabilities": {
        "liabilities1": {},
        "liabilities2": {}
    }
}
```

the purpose of having dictionaries like above in `session_state` is i can summarize per respective groups like `total per aset1` or `total per aset`.
and the following code is executed in `app.py`

```
input_number("Cash on Hand",session_name='how_do_i_set_cash_on_hand_value_from_this_number_input')
```

i'm a bit confused because in the [streamlit pages](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) it defines how to use a session_state not in dictionary type.

how / where do i start?

Comment: See my answer - not sure this is what you're asking for though so if not please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You simply read/write your data as follows

```
data = {
    "asset": {
        "asset1": {
            "cash_on_hand": 1,
            "account_receivable": 2
        },
        "asset2": {}
    },
    "liabilities": {
        "liabilities1": {},
        "liabilities2": {}
    }
}

# write
st.session_state['data'] = data

# read
data = st.session_state['data']
```

You can use whatever key you want - i.e. if you have multiple data you can use multiple different keys, i.e.

```
st.session_state['data_1'] = ...
st.session_state['data_2'] = ...
```

Since it's essentially a `dict` that is persistent between script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. Create a form to receive data input. Also create a dict session variable with key **data** and initialize it. Everytime the button is pressed, data will be added to existing values.

In the demo, I only add 2 input widgets.

Note when your refresh the page, session variable will be lost. To preserve the data you have to save it either locally or in the cloud. Save to json, csv, sqlite, etc. When you start the app, load the data in session variable instead of DATA_INIT.

#### Code

```
import streamlit as st


# Define and initialize the data so that it is easier to update.
DATA_INIT = {
    "asset": {
        "asset1": {
            "cash_on_hand": 0,
            "account_receivable": 0
        },
        "asset2": {
            "cash_on_hand": 0,
            "account_receivable": 0
        }
    },
    "liabilities": {
        "liabilities1": {
            'current': 0
        },
        "liabilities2": {
            'current': 0
        }
    }
}


if 'data' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['data'] = DATA_INIT

st.markdown('### Data Entry')
with st.form('accounting', clear_on_submit=True):
    coh = st.number_input('Asset 1 / Cash On Hand', value=0.0, step=0.01)
    ar = st.number_input('Asset 1 / Account Receivable', value=0.0, step=0.01)

    # add other input here.

    submit = st.form_submit_button('save')

if submit:
    st.session_state['data']['asset']['asset1']['cash_on_hand'] += coh
    st.session_state['data']['asset']['asset1']['account_receivable'] += ar

st.markdown('### Current Data')
with st.expander('Current data', expanded=False):
    st.json(st.session_state['data'])
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: then how do you calculate / total per `asset1` or `asset2` and total per `asset`?

Comment: To get the total for asset1, just add the cash_on_hand and account_receivable values.
`total_asset1 = st.session_state['data']['asset']['asset1']['cash_on_hand'] + st.session_state['data']['asset']['asset1']['account_receivable']`, the same can be done for `total_asset2` but use `asset2` instead of `asset1`. To get the total asset just add `total_asset1` and `total_asset2`.